# Alternative for using @Nullable for double in Java Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dto, spring-annotations

I've made a class for request body, now it has a double field which might come in request body sometimes and sometimes it won't, how should I handle it? Sample code:

```
@Nullable
private String phoneNumber;
[what should be here?]
private double amount;
```

Comment: Either make it a `Double`, or accept that its value will be `0` when it wasn't included.

Comment: How to make its value 0 when it wasn't included? Which annotation?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it is the default behaviour (but then again, I believe you wouldn't need to annotate with `@Nullable` either, so maybe I'm missing something here).